# DigitalOcean - Access localhost from the DigitalOcean droplet

Tags: docker

I have recently created a droplet on DigitalOcean and installed Docker on the server. I ran
`docker container run -d -p 8080:80 nginx` on the server. This command runs perfectly, as checked by `docker ps` command.
But how do I access the `localhost:8080` on DigitalOcean server as `localhost:8080` on my machine doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out the public IP address or DNS name of your DigitalOcean server. Then use either *ipaddress*:8080 or *dnsname*:8080.

localhost refers only to the local machine and is mapped to the 127.0.0.1 IP address. It can only be accessed from the machine itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to access it by localhost:8080 on your local machine, it will search your local machine. It's a loopback destination, you may know it by 127.0.0.1

If you want to access you digitalocean droplet on your local machine, you can use :8080